# passing options when using methods in a rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, facebooker2

I'm using [this gem](https://github.com/fionnbharra/facebooker2) for Facebook authentication in my Rails app.

I'm having some issues in IE and I think it's because of an issue in the Javascript in [this file](https://github.com/fionnbharra/facebooker2/blob/master/lib/facebooker2/rails/helpers/javascript.rb#L45) -

If you look at line 52, it seems I can pass options into channelUrl.

I'm implementing a login button like this -

```
<%= fb_login(:text=>"Log in") %>
```

Can I do this from my app, or do I need to edit the gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I look at the [README](https://github.com/fionnbharra/facebooker2#readme), you should have a partial like this one:

```
<%= fb_connect_async_js %>
<% if current_facebook_user %>
  <%= "Welcome #{current_facebook_user.first_name} #{current_facebook_user.last_name}!" %>
  or
  <%= "Hello #{fb_name(current_facebook_user, :useyou => false)}!" # link to facebook profile %>
  <%= fb_logout_link("Logout of fb", request.url) %><br />
<% else
   # you must explicitly request permissions for facebook user fields.
   # here we instruct facebook to ask the user for permission for our website
   # to access the user's facebook email and birthday
   %>
  <%= fb_login(:text => 'Log in', :perms => 'email,user_birthday') %>
<% end %>
```

In that case, you just have to pass the options to `fb_connect_async_js`:

```
<%= fb_connect_async_js :channel_url => 'http://blahblah' %>
... rest of the partial ...
```

If your partial doesn't look like the one above, you should edit your question to post yours (the full one).

Comment: thanks again, at this rate I'm going to have to send you my salary this month.

Comment: @user597264 I'll need facebook integration later this month, my answers are a bit self-serving ;-)

Comment: My only advice would be to do cross browser testing as early on as possible. I'm in a world of pain trying to sort out some Internet explorer login issues.